# How to get corresponding cluster name of a managed server using wlst?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I deployed two weblogic managed instance. These two instance are deployed on different cluster.

My question is how to get cluster name of the managed server in runtime?

For example, if in instance1, I want to get cluster_1, if in instance2, I want to get cluster_2.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code : 
    domainConfig()
    cd('Servers')
    cd('instance1')
    cluster=cmo.getCluster()
    clusterName=cluster.getName()
    print clusterName